# Can a CSS class selector be applied to a component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components, angular-component-router

I have the following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J2Q0Q7wBk1McEAyUHPOx?p=preview) that uses ui-router and Angular's 1.6x new component feature.

The state `'userRegister'` becomes active then initialises the `'userRegister'` component. This component injects a new `<user-register/>` into the `<ui-view>` then injects the HTML contents of the `ng-template` script block, which is all working fine.

The final DOM ends up being:

```
<ui-view class="ng-scope">
    <user-register class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <h1 class="header">Create account</h1>
    </user-register>
</ui-view>
```

However, I cannot find a way to add a CSS class selector to the `<user-register/>` tag.

e.g. using a class selector called `.example` I'd like to achieve the following:

`<user-register class="example ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">...<user-register/>`

Any ideas please?

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS class. CSS has rulesets, selectors, class selectors, rules, and properties (all of which are sometimes mistakenly called "CSS classes"). HTML has actual classes.

Comment: @Quentin : of course, will attempt to update to 'class selector'

Comment: @Iamme can't you just have a div inside your template (with your class applied) and keep everything of your content inside of it to achieve similar behaviour?

Comment: @tanmay : yes, I have that now. But I wanted to avoid that extra nesting tag if possible as it seems superfluous to requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you could always wrap the template on a div and put the class there.

If don't want to do it, you can inject the `$element` and use the `$postLink` function to add the class you need:

```
.component('userRegister', {
    templateUrl: '/views/user-register',
    controller: function($element) {
       this.$postLink = function() {
         $element.addClass('example');
       }
    }
 })
```

Here is the working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VuWu8L9VqrgJRGnxItY2?p=preview

Final DOM:

```
<user-register class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope example">
  <h1 class="header">Create account</h1>
</user-register>
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you happen to know where a verbose API reference is for the $postLink method and $element? I've looked on the Angular site but can only find the $postLink function mentioned within the developer guide.

Comment: For anyone interested: `$postLink` is referred to as a _lifecycle hook_. Some info on this hook and others can be found via the proceeding link, although I'm yet to find a fully comprehensive explanation (please share if you find anything decent): [Angular 1.5 lifecycle hooks by Todd](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#postlink)